# How to save Axios result in array to use in Vue.js v-for?

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

My problem is with using an Axios response in Vue.js; it seems that the data is not saved to the array (`newBox`).

I want to save API-returned values to an array for use with `v-for` in the component.

```html
<script setup>
  import {
    RouterLink,
    RouterView
  } from 'vue-router';

  import {
    onMounted,
    onUnmounted
  } from 'vue'

  import Box from './components/Box.vue';

  import axios from "axios"
  import {
    propsToAttrMap
  } from '@vue/shared';

  var newBox = new Array();

  onMounted(() => {
    getPosts();
  })

  async function getPosts() {
    try {
      const url = `https://someurl.ir/api/v1/api.php`
      const response = await axios.get(url)
      this.newBox = response.data
      }))
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response) {
        // client received an error response (5xx, 4xx)
        console.log("Server Error:", err)
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="NewBoxRibbon">
    <Box v-for="title in newBox" :msg="title" />
  </div>

  <RouterView />
</template>

<style scoped>
  .NewBoxRibbon{
    scrollbar-width: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;
    /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
  }
</style>
```

I used `fetch` and it too seems that in function `getPosts` it couldn't modify the array `newBox`...

Even when I define a variable and try to modify it in the function `getPosts`, can't do!!

Comment: Is that `}))` at the end of the `try` block in `getPosts` a typo? Unrelated to the question probably, but it is a fatal syntax error, and makes it just a little bit harder for us to test your code if we want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `newBox` as a ref property then update by reponse `newBox.value = response.data`:

```js
 import {
    onMounted,
    onUnmounted,
    ref
  } from 'vue'

 // ....
  var newBox = ref([]);
//....

   const response = await axios.get(url)
     newBox.value = response.data
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `await` be in an async function?

Comment: Yes, I just kept the relevant statement  to make the answer  more clear

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

- Import `ref` from `'vue'`
- Define `newBox` as `const newBox = ref([])`
- Use `newBox` as `newBox.value` instead of `this.newBox`

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

// ...

const newBox = ref([])

// ...

newBox.value = response.data
```

### Full story

The reason why `newBox` is not being updated is that you are creating it as a plain array. In Vue, things that require reactivity (like `v-for`, computed properties, watchers, etc.) require you to use a `ref` of `reactive` object.

For example:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

const newBox = ref([])
```

The value of the ref is then accessed on the `.value` property:

```js
newBox.value = response.data
```

You do not need to use `.value` in the template in most cases, as it is automatically unwrapped (only a single level, so objects of refs will still require you to use `.value`, but that's probably more than you need to know right now).

Notes:

- You do not need to use `this` in `script setup`, you can pretty much act as if it is a regular JS script.
- Prefer `let` and `const` over `var`. For `ref`s use `const`, as they are never reassigned.
- Prefer array literals over the `new Array()` syntax.
- I'm not sure what you are using `propsToAttrMap` for (I have never even heard of it), but if you really need it, at least import it from `'vue'` not `'@vue/shared'`.

I have incorporated these notes into the following code, and left out the parts that are not directly relevant (HTML, `onUnmounted`, etc.).
I have also removed the `}))` in the `try` block in `getPosts`, as they should not be there.

So your JS code would then look like this:

```js
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";

import axios from "axios";

const newBox = ref([]);

onMounted(() => {
  getPosts();
});

async function getPosts() {
  try {
    const url = `https://someurl.ir/api/v1/api.php`;
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    newBox.value = response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      // client received an error response (5xx, 4xx)
      console.log("Server Error:", err);
    }
  }
}
```

Extra advice: you should almost always use the `key` attribute on the `v-for` element ([List Rendering - Maintaining State with `key`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key)).

Also, the Vue docs are excellent! Most questions can be answered just by reading the relevant section.

Useful doc links:

- [Reactivity Fundamentals](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html)
- [List Rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer. If you do not wrap the variable in a ref(), you are not using the reactivity part of the Composition API and thus the DOM is not updating.

It also appears you have extra closing parens in your try block, and note the 'this' keyword is not applicable in setup() functions. See VueJS docs regarding moving from Options API to Composition API and handling 'this'.

Finally, double-check that the response dot notation is correct. Are you certain that `response.data` is sufficient for traversing the JSON response or should it be `response.data.posts` perhaps? Console log the response to be sure.

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from "vue-router";
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import Box from "./components/Box.vue";
import axios from "axios";

var newBox = ref([]);

onMounted(() => {
  getPosts();
});

async function getPosts() {
  try {
    const url = "https://someurl.ir/api/v1/api.php";
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    this.newBox.value = response.data.posts;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      // client received an error response (5xx, 4xx)
      console.log("Server Error:", err);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
   <div class="NewBoxRibbon">
    <Box v-for="title in newBox" :msg="title" :key="title" />
  </div>

  <RouterView />
</template>
```

Comment: hi and thanks a lot!! one problem solved and another come! i dont know what to use instead of response.data.posts...

Comment: Depends on the server.  Try console.log(response.data) after your axios.get() to see the data structure. Sometimes responses are sent as a ‘data’ object, so you may want to try response.data.data

Comment: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] its my response.data

Comment: <NewBookBox v-for="(book) in newBooks" :bookTitle="book.title"/> find it!! thanks a lot

Comment: Great! Glad to see it is working now.